# How to read field from JSON encoding of XML message

Tags: python, json, xml, python-2.7

Is there a way I can get the `errorMessage` tag from this response using some code in python?

```
{  
   "movies_search":{  
      "@xmlns":"http://www.ourmoviest.com/mv",
      "@xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
      "@xsi:schemaLocation":"http://www.ourmoviest.com/mv mv.xsd ",
      "error":{  
         "errorMessage":"We cannot proceed search",
         "statusCode":"00004"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Python script,

```
import json
respStr = """
{  
   "movies_search":{  
      "@xmlns":"http://www.ourmoviest.com/mv",
      "@xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
      "@xsi:schemaLocation":"http://www.ourmoviest.com/mv mv.xsd ",
      "error":{  
         "errorMessage":"We cannot proceed search",
         "statusCode":"00004"
      }
   }
}
"""
respObj = json.loads(respStr)
print respObj['movies_search']['error']['errorMessage']
```

will print the `errorMessage` string,

```
We cannot proceed search
```

as requested.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html "Decoding JSON".

(I'm really tempted to simply ask "what have you tried yourself to reach the goal"...)

Edit: as requested by the first comment, here the essential code instead of a link-only answer:

```
import json;

responseJson = json.loads(response)
responseJson['movies_search']['error']['errorMessage']
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I have adjusted the answer.